# Singleton returns null when accessed by threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, singleton, ejb

As the title states I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue where some threads which read data from a Singleton get a null value. My investigation into our logs read as though its a concurrency issue.

The Singleton is defined as follows:

```
@Singleton
public class StaticDatabaseEntries {

private static final Map<String,Thing> databaseEntries = new HashMap<>();

@Lock(LockType.READ)
public Thing getThing(String index) {
return databaseEntries.get(index);
}
}
```

At first I was under the impression that only one element within the data was corrupted as access to the same item is repeatededly returning null. Further access to debug entries show that the issue appears isolated to a specific thread. It's as though once whatever occurs that induces the null return on a thread continues to do so but only on the affected thread.

An earlier version of this class did not apply the `LockType.READ` so per the specification a `LockType.WRITE` is assumed. I deployed an update with the correct lock to enable concurrent read. This did not improve the situation.

The data is loaded into the HashMap from a database upon deployment and remains unchange for the duration. Since the class isn't tagged with `@Startup` the application instead uses a context listener to trigger the loading of the entries from database.

With threads primarily performing a read activity I don't believe a switch to `ConcurrentHashMap` is benficial. I am considering removing the `static final` portion as it seems unnecessary when the container is managing concurrent access and the singleton lifecycle. I have experienced side effects when the container cannot subclass/proxy things which are marked as `final` in EJBs.

The other possibility I've considered is there is some manner of bug in the container software. This is running on a older Java 1.7 and JBOSS 6 EAP. Worst case I'll have to forego the singleton pattern and instead load the entries from the database on demand.

Comment: Have you conclusively excluded the simple possibility that an entry in the map contains a null value because it was written with a null value?

Comment: Yes. The initial load from the database is logged, indicating those which later show as null  do exist. Prior to the entry becoming null on one thread the service is operating correctly as logs indicate the particular element is accessed/used.

Comment: In java EE, the default for `@Singleton` session beans is to have concurrency managed by the container. 
Just start by removing the `@Lock` annotation and make the map NOT static: the container already guarantees it to be a singleton. You should instantiate, populate and assign the map inside a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` (the container will call this prior to make the bean available to be injected elsewhere).
Also, if the data never changes during the lifetime of the app, why not make the map immutable? (guava/pcollections)

Comment: In similar cases in the past I went with Bean-managed concurrency (i.e. DIY). The map would be immutable, and the reference would be volatile (i.e. every write to the reference are visibile to subsequent read). With this approach, you still "write" the map reference only during `@Postconstruct` and all concurrent reads are fine. Note that in this scenario since writes are always overwriting a complete map... they can happen concurrently as well.

Answer (score 0):

In general: If you work with threads, read activity can cause problems, if you are calling an object method, that isn't thread-save! This is exactly what often leads to undetectable errors in larger projects.

`HashMap` isn't thread-safe!

You should switch to `ConcurrentHashMap`.

For further details, have a look at this article: https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrent-map

Comment: This is a topic on which I've been left wondering what is the best approach. This software is Java Enterprise so we tend to make use of container features. In this case its the `@Singleton` annotation which the container is supposed to guarantee concurrency. So in such scenarios as this must the underlying data structure also be tread safe as in your suggestion of a `ConcurrentHashMap`? That has seemed redundant to me given the EJB specification of a singleton.

Comment: I'll also say that as far as I've seen, the concurrent data structures primarily lock around/during write activities. Most of the time we use a `@Singleton`  to load and hold configuration data in memory. The load is a one time write activity and all other access is a read. The tendency towards read activities on top of the EJB specification for container managed concurrency is why I haven't seen our project use write locked data structures often. Are we wrong to do so? As suggested even reads can be an issue, so what is best for high read activities?

Comment: In Bean managed concurrency, the container doesn't control simultaneous access of Singleton Session Bean by clients. The developer is required to implement concurrency by themselves, see https://www.baeldung.com/java-ee-singleton-session-bean  For my understanding this means ```StaticDatabaseEntries``` is  managed as singleton correctly by the container, but methodes inside ithe object have to implement concurrency itself. Please correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: It is my understanding that the container by default applies/assumes that is should manage the concurrency of EJBs, unless otherwise specified to use bean managed concurrency. It then also applies/assumes a `LockType.WRITE` for all functions unless otherwise specified. This is why our code does not implement any locking, and again why I believe using a `ConcurrentHashMap` is redundant. Using a concurrent datastructure within an EJB whose concurrency is managed by the container is creating two layers of locking.